# C# - Serial Port - Data Received Event - Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, serial-port

Currently i am busy with Serial port programming using C# and very new to this stuff. I have built one console app... In this app, I am polling a RS 232 device every 200 ms. The device must respond to the poll with one byte response each time.

Most of the times, I am getting the expected byte thru Data Received event. But, sometimes the  data received event is not firing...  Even, i tried to read the available bytes after each poll.. I dont get the expected bytes.

After spending lot of time with no luck, i was accidentally opened browser while the serial port app was running.  Suddenly, the data received event started firing for each poll... After browser gets opened, few seconds later the event didnt fire again. I tried opening some other apps, the same behavious continued. For few seconds, events get fired and no events after that.   It seems if CPU is busy , the data received event works fine.

Can someone encountered the same issue? Please advice on how to make sure Data Received event fires each time.  Thanks!

Please find a sample code below.

```
Every 200 ms.


Serial.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Mark;
Thread.Sleep(2);
Serial.Write(0x01, 0, 1);
Thread.Sleep(1);
Serial.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Space;
Thread.Sleep(2);`
```

Comment: I don't know how did you manage the receiving. But me, I added a class which herits from EventArgs with an Accessor named Data.

Comment: Can you show the code?  Where is the code that sends the poll?

Comment: It will help if you show your code, a verbal description of a problem is not good enough most times. What do you mean by polling the serial port? The datareceived event fires when bytes arrive, no extra polling should be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

If's very reasonable to expect incoming data to be passed as an argument to an event handler.  Unfortunately, the `DataReceived` event doesn't do this, and is generally just a stupid design.

I suggest that you instead call `BeginRead` on the `BaseStream` of the serial port, and provide a callback.  Then you get your event and your data together when it arrives.

A benefit of using chained calls to `BeginRead` is that if the serial buffer contained multiple messages, you will get multiple `BeginRead` callbacks.  While with `DataReceived` you have to check `BytesAvailable` and figure out how many messages and partial messages are in the buffer, because if you don't read them all, things get stuck.

In general, I find the `Ports.IO.SerialPort` class provided with .NET to be completely useless, and for my work I use the Win32 API instead (I made my own .NET wrapper).